# Using Moq With Word Interop collections

Tags: c#, moq, office-interop

I have a class that takes an Interop.Word.Range object and creates a list from it. I'm trying to create a test that specifically tests the Bookmarks in the range. Therefore, I'm trying to mock this.

```
// this works
var mockBookmark = new Mock<Word::Bookmark>();
mockBookmark.Setup(b => b.Name).Returns("A Bookmark");
var bm1 = mockBookmark.Object;
// this works
var mockRange = new Mock<Word::Range>();
mockRange.Setup(f => f.Text).Returns("This is the text");
mockRange.Setup(f => f.Bookmarks).Returns(bookmarks);
var range = mockRange.Object;
// this doesn't
var mockBookmarks = new Mock<Word::Bookmarks>();
mockBookmarks.SetupGet(b => b[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(bm1);
var bookmarks = mockBookmarks.Object;
```

But no matter what I put in that b[It.IsAny()] (I've tried ints, strings, and wildcards) call I get

```
Failure: Setup: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array
```

on that line. I thought the whole point of mocking was that YOU'RE defining the bounds of the array, but apparently something isn't clicking for me.

I'm certainly willing to entertain the possibility that I'm going at this completely the wrong way, but I need to be able to define a Range that contains multiple Bookmark objects that have different names, as that's what I'm testing.

Comment: have you tried returning a lambda in stead?
.Returns (index => bm1)

Comment: that doesn't even build. I tried .Returns(() => vm1) and that will build, but it makes no difference. I don't think the Return is what is causing the error.